# Is there a way to avoid array-to-pointer decay?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

The parameter to main `char* argv[]` decays to `char**`, which is unfortunate, because it cannot be used with `std::begin` which only accepts arrays. The only workaround I see is to use a variable length array which is undesirable.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* _argv[argc];
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
        _argv[i] = argv[i];

    for (arg : _argv)
    {
        std::cout << arg << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Desirably I want something like: `char* _argv[] = { ... };`

Comment: In fact, you don't even have array to pointer decay. `argv` really is `char**`. But what problem re you string to solve?

Comment: `char* _argv[argc];` is not standard C++, since there are no variable length arrays in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The only workaround I see is to use a variable length array which is
>   undesirable.

The only workaround for what exactly? There is no problem. If you actually need an array of `string`s, use a `vector` as shown in TNAs answer; I doubt you need to modify the parameters though. 

If you just need to iterate through it, there is no need to copy all the pointers.

```
for (auto str : boost::make_iterator_range(argv, argv + argc))
    std::cout << str;
```

Or

```
for (auto ptr = argv; ptr != argv + argc; ++ptr)
    std::cout << *ptr << '\n';
```

> The parameter to `main` `char* argv[]` decays to `char**`, which is
>   unfortunate, because it cannot be used with `std::begin` which only
>   accepts arrays.

There is no other way. The amount of command line parameters is not known at compile time, and this method of passing them (instead of using two pointers-to-pointers) is historically motivated.

Comment: Thank you for a solution that has no memory allocations.

Answer (score 6):

That is not possible, since the signature of main is fixed. You can copy the elements to a `vector` using:

```
std::vector<std::string> args {argv, argv + argc};
```

Then you can use `std::begin` on `args`

Answer (score 5):

You can define a simple class wrapper to give you `begin()` and `end()`.

```
struct Args {
    int argc_;
    char **argv_;
    Args (int argc, char *argv[]) : argc_(argc), argv_(argv) {}
    char ** begin () { return argv_; }
    char ** end () { return argv_ + argc_; }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (auto s : Args(argc, argv)) {
        std::cout << s << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```